# Haskell Word8 to Text format

Tags: haskell, text, types

I am looking for the best way to convert from Word8 to Text, the issue being that using the runChildrenWithText function for Heist requires text input for binding, yet the getParam functionality returns ByteStrings which I can convert to Word8 but not Text from either of these formats, so I am having trouble deciding on where to go from here, any help regarding the best way to resolve this is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Heist, but it sounds to me like you don't want to convert `Word8` to `Text`. Instead you want to convert either `[Word8]` or `ByteString` to `Text`. Is that correct?

Comment: ByteString to Text would probably be most useful, the only reason I have mentioned Word8 to Text is because I have managed to find how to convert ByteStrings to Word8.

Answer (score 5):

The [`Data.Text.Encodings`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.3.1/doc/html/Data-Text-Encoding.html) package has many methods of converting `ByteString`s to `Text`. Note that it's possible for a `ByteString` to `Text` encoding to *fail* (say, you are assuming the `ByteString` contains UTF-8 data but it actually doesn't) so this is a more complex process than just `convert :: ByteString -> Text`.

To wit, `decodeUtf8 :: ByteString -> Text` will throw impure exceptions, so `decodeUtf8' :: ByteString -> Either UnicodeException Text` may be preferable if there's any chance of a decode failure.

You can also build more sophisticated decode failure handler schemes using `decodeUtf8With :: OnDecodeError -> ByteString -> Text` and [`Data.Text.Encodings.Error`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.3.1/doc/html/Data-Text-Encoding-Error.html).

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are the other encodings used by `ByteString`

Comment: `ByteString` isn't encoded, it's essentially just `Vector Word8`, pure binary data. For convenience it has an `IsString` instance which lets you pretend like it's a `String`. `Text` is UTF-16 encoded, but you can think of it as `Vector`s of Unicode code points. Functions that take `ByteString` to `Text` assume that the `ByteString` is some kind of encoded code point stream and then upcast it to Unicode and store it as UTF-16. That first assumption might fail, thus leading to errors.

Comment: @DiegoNolan Here's a [list of common encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings). Like tel said, the ByteString is nothing but bytes. For those bytes to be convertible into text in any way, you have to use a character encoding.